# Conversion from Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator to spherical (WGS84) coordinates in Matlab

Tags: matlab, coordinate-transformation

I have an array of x & y coordinates in the Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator projection (EPSG 3857) and wish to convert it to the normal lat/long spherical projection system (EPSG: 4326) in Matlab. 
In Open Earth Toolbox there is a routine which is used for conversion of co-ordinates, although, conversion to and from Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator is not yet supported.

Does anyone have any information regarding the conversion? A formula to guide can also be helpful which I can integrate in Matlab.

Thanks!

Comment: http://georepository.com/projection_3856/Popular-Visualisation-Pseudo-Mercator.html Can this help you?

Comment: Thanks! I wrote a script to convert it in matlab based on this formula. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIYF?
http://georepository.com/projection_3856/Popular-Visualisation-Pseudo-Mercator.html

> Note: These formulas have been transcribed from EPSG Guidance Note
>   #7-2. Users are encouraged to use that document rather than the text which follows as reference because limitations in the transcription
>   will be avoided.
>
> This method is utilised by some popular web mapping and visualisation
>   applications. It applies standard Mercator (Spherical) formulas
>   (method code 1026) to ellipsoidal coordinates and the sphere radius is
>   taken to be the semi-major axis of the ellipsoid. This approach only
>   approximates to the more rigorous application of ellipsoidal formulas
>   to ellipsoidal coordinates (as given in EPSG dataset coordinate
>   operation method codes 9804 and 9805).  Unlike either the spherical or
>   ellipsoidal Mercator projection methods, this method is not conformal:
>   scale factor varies as a function of azimuth, which creates angular
>   distortion. Despite angular distortion there is no convergence in the
>   meridian.
>
> The formulas to derive projected Easting and Northing coordinates from
>   ellipsoidal latitude (lat) and longitude (lon) first derive the radius
>   of the sphere (R) from:   R = a
>
> Then applying spherical Mercator formulae:
>
> E = FE + R(lon - lonO)                  N = FN + R ln[tan(pi/4 +
>   lat/2)]                    where FE and FN are false easting and false
>   nothing at the projection origin, other symbols are as listed above
>   and logarithms are natural.
>
> If latitude lat = 90º, N is infinite. The above formula for N will
>   fail near to the pole, and should not be used poleward of 88º.
>
> The reverse formulas to derive latitude and longitude on the sphere
>   from E and N values are:  D = -(N-FN)/R = (FN-N)/R    lat = pi/2 - 2
>   atan(e^D) where e=base of natural logarithms, 2.7182818...    lon = [(E
>   - FE)/R] + lonO
>
> If q_alpha is the scale factor at a given azimuth alpha, it is a
>   function of R', the radius of curvature at that azimuth derived from:
>     R' = rho nu / (nu cos^2alpha + rho sin^2alpha)  q_alpha = R / (R' cos
>   lat) where rho and nu are the radii of curvature of the ellipsoid at
>   latitude lat in the plane of the meridian and perpendicular to the
>   meridian respectively; rho = a(1 - e^2)/(1 - e^2 sin^2(lat))^3/2 nu =
>   a /(1 - e^2 sin^2(lat))^1/2
>
> Then when the azimuth is 0º, 180º, 90º or 270º the scale factors in
>   the meridian (h) and on the parallel (k) are:     q_0 = q_180  = h = R /
>   (rho cos(lat))    q_90 = q_270 = k = R / (nu cos(lat)) which
>   demonstrates the non-conformallity of the Pseudo Mercator method.
>
> Maximum angular distortion omega is a function of latitude and is
>   found from:   omega = 2 asin{[ABS(h - k)] / (h + k)}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to get the coordinates of some spatial points that my model generated in R and it took me hours to find a solution.

What I have done, after all, was import my maps to QGIS (very simple to install) and then save the map (right click->save as) as an actual WGS84 and not psedo Merc.

I hope this will help others too.